# Django IntegrityError error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

Getting IntegrityError if I try to enter data through CBV CreateView but everything works fine through admin panel.

Model:

```
class Account(Info):
    firm = models.ForeignKey(
        Firm
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    is_default = models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES
    )
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=ACCOUNT_CATEGORIES
    )
    sub_category = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=ACCOUNT_SUB_CATEGORIES
    )
    show_in = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=SHOW_IN
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = [
            'name'
        ]
        unique_together = (
            'firm', 'name'
        )
```

View:

```
class CreateAccountView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = CreateAccountForm
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    template_name = 'create_templates/create_account.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateAccountView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        firm_obj = self.get_firm_obj(self.kwargs.get('f_id'))
        context['firm_obj'] = firm_obj
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.firm = self.get_firm_obj(self.kwargs.get('f_id'))
        form.instance.is_default = False
        form.instance.sub_category = '4'
        super(CreateAccountView, self).form_valid(form)
        return HttpResponse(
            '''
            <script>
                window.close();
                window.onunload = refreshParent; function refreshParent() {
                window.opener.location.reload();
                }
            </script>
            '''
        )

    @staticmethod
    def get_firm_obj(f_id):
        return get_object_or_404(Firm, id=f_id)
```

Form:

```
class CreateAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(
        label='Account Name', max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = (
            'name', 'type',
            'category', 'show_in'
        )
        widgets = {
            'type': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }
            ),
            'category': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }
            ),
            'show_in': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }
            )
        }
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\kaizentech\emuneem\emuneem\girvi\utils.py" in dispatch
  17.         return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  207.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  173.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\workspace\kaizentech\emuneem\emuneem\muneem\views\create_views\create_account_view.py" in form_valid
  25.         super(CreateAccountView, self).form_valid(form)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in form_valid
  149.         self.object = form.save()
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
  457.                              construct=False)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save_instance
  103.         instance.save()
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  590.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  618.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  699.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  732.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  921.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  920.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\PrImE\envs\kaizentech\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  485.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /add_account/f/1/
Exception Value: columns firm_id, name are not unique
```

Using `sqlite` for development. Everything is working fine through admin panel if I try to enter duplicate entry through admin panel I get `Account with this Firm and Name already exists.` which is correct but why I'm not seeing this error via CBV

Comment: @FunkyBob Thanks...If you can please add your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've excluded `firm` from the form, and don't add it until after validation, so there's no way the form can validate that the combination of firm and name is unique. You'll need to pass it int the form some other way and check explicitly in the form's `clean` method that there is no existing instance with that combination.

Answer (score 0):

This definition means "Account with this Firm and Name already exists." You are receiving the same error in both cases,

```
unique_together = (
    'firm', 'name'
)
```

Exception Value: columns firm_id, name are not unique, that means the same as the admin panel error.